# How to make a list of lists display vertically

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, format

So I have a list L.

```
L = [[1],[2,3],[3,4,5]]
```

How would I go about to make it look like this.

```
1  2  3
   3  4
      5
```

I want this to be able to iterate.
I think the best way would be nested for loops, but I am confused on where to begin.

EDIT***

I managed to make something that resembles what I want to do.

```
L = [[1],[2,3],[3,4,5],[]]
max_list= []

maxlen=max(len(l) for l in L)
for row in range(maxlen):
    max_list.append([])
    for col in tab:
        try:
            max_list[row].append(col[row])
        except:
            max_list[row].append('')
for col in max_list:
    print(col)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, '']
['', 3, 4, '']
['', '', 5, '']
```

As of right now how would I format it to

```
1  2  3
   3  4
      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions are not so elegant, too much code...

```
L = [[1],[2,3],[3,4,5]]
max_length = max(map(len, L))  # finding max length
output = zip(*map(lambda x: x + [' '] * (max_length - len(x)), L))  # filling every sublist with ' ' to max_length and then zipping it
for i in output: print(*i)  # printing whole result
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
  3 4
    5
```

So 3rd line is not that obvious, i will break it down

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x + [' '] * (max_length - len(x)), L))
[[1, ' ', ' '], [2, 3, ' '], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> list(zip(*map(lambda x: x + [' '] * (max_length - len(x)), L)))
[(1, 2, 3), (' ', 3, 4), (' ', ' ', 5)]
```

**UPDATE**

To lengthen the spaces you need to provide keyword argument `sep` to [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function: `for i in output: print(*i, sep= '  ')`

Comment: Thank you. This is probably a stupid question, but is there a way to lengthen the spaces in between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are just trying to print it in that format, how about this code:

```
L = [[1],[2,3],[3,4,5]]


#1  2  3
#   3  4
#      5

for i in range(len(L)):
  for lst in L:
    if (i == 0):
      print (lst[0], end='')
    if (i == 1 and len(lst)>1):
      print (lst[1], end='')
    if (i == 2 and len(lst)>2):
      print (lst[2], end='')
  print ('\n')
```

it only works for this specific case, where `L = [[1],[2,3],[3,4,5]]` but it prints the desired output.